# How would you go about implementing this example of Resolution in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, first-order-logic

This is perhaps one of the simpler examples of Resolution in FOL there is, but I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around how this would look like written in Prolog:

```
∀x. GradStudent(x) ⊃ Student(x)
∀x. Student(x) ⊃ HardWorker(x)
GradStudent(sue)
```

The query is `KB |= HardWorker(sue)`. I can see how you'd go about manually doing the Resolution, but I'm lost as to how this would look like in Prolog.

Where I'm getting stuck is the `HardWorker` predicate, there is no explicit definition of `HardWorker` and of course that is not valid in Prolog.

Answer (score 1):

Turn the arrow around:

```
hardworker(X) :- student(X).

student(X) :- gradstudent(X).

gradstudent(sue).
```

So we go on and ask if `sue` is a hard worker:

```
?- hardworker(sue).
true.
```

Note the incompleteness of this all:
There are other hard workers than just students. There are other kinds of students than grad students. And Sue is probably not the only grad student.